# iOS NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am getting this error whenever I try making a request to our server. It was working fine before we setup SSL, not it is all messed up..here is my code:

```
  // Setup URL POST Request..
NSString* code4ArmourUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.code4armour.com/index.php/user/login?"];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:code4ArmourUrl ]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"00000000000000000000000000000000" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-api-key"];

NSString* postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",emailString,passwordString];
postString = [postString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2b"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// Make URL POST Request..
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError* connectionError) {
```

Any reason why this isn't working..I believe it is an issue with SSL but I don't know how to get around this without doing something hacky that Apple won't end up accepting on to the App Store?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to successfully send requests using cURL on your Mac? Are you sure the server is working? Are you missing headers defining authentication data?

Comment: No issues using cURL on my Mac..weird stuff going on here! HELPP!

Comment: It looks like in cURL that it is not validating the certificate..is this my issue? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server is not set up correctly. While it probably has a properly signed certificate it is missing the chain certificates leading to the trusted root. See the problems reported by [SSLLabs analysis](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.code4armour.com) about additional certificates and the certification path.

How to configure these missing intermediate certificates depends on your server.
For more information see [Godaddy support site](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/868/what-is-an-intermediate-certificate).

Comment: Thanks brother, this helped us locate the issue.

Comment: Hey @Steffen you seem to be very knowledgable on this matter..when you went to the SSLLabs Analysis did you see anything that may be causing my NSURLConnection to do this?

Comment: @MikeSimz: Look at the parts I mentioned and you will see "Chain issues - Incomplete" and an "Extra Download" in the certification path.